# Right mouse click is disabled in MinGW bash shell, how to restore

Tags: windows, bash, mingw, right-mouse-button

When I run the MinGW bash shell, I can no longer open the right-mouse menu. when I exit the shell, and return to the `cmd.exe` shell, the right mouse button works again.

Is the MinGW bash version disabling the mouse button somehow? and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not implemented, but you can right click the window title and the menu should pop up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that seams to work too though it is less convenient compared to right clicks everywhere.